# Issue in selectOneMenu in primefaces?

Tags: primefaces

I am using primefaces 3.2 and i have used selectOneMenu from primefaces.When i drag and drop somethine into the selectOneMenu box it displaying some url(for example drag and drop the image into the selectOneMenu).Text box allows that drag and drop but why selectOneMenu.How to avoid that.

```
 <p:selectOneMenu value="#{buttonBean.number}">  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 1" itemValue="1" />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 2" itemValue="2" />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 3" itemValue="3" />  
        </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Primefaces 3.2 uses an html input to display the selected value.
If you can, update to 3.4. The helper input is gone, no this issue.
You can test it in the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/selectOneMenu.jsf).